# Where are fonts located, which where insalled from file?

Tags: fonts, uninstall

I installed a few fonts lately simply by clicking on the file and hitting the install button in the window that opened.
Now, I wanted to uninstall a few of them.
As far as I know, the fonts should have gotten installed system wide, but they did not.
There are none of the newly installed fonts in `/usr/share/fonts`, and I have neither a `~/.fonts` nor a `/usr/local/share/fonts` directory, which leaves me a bit puzzled as to where I have to go to delete them.

So, I installed the font manager, but it also only shows me what seem to be the pre-installed fonts of the system for system wide fonts and shows no user specific fonts.

I use Fedora 20.

Answer (score 0):

You can see where are the fonts and where were installed with:

`fc-list` – lists fonts